# Javascript i++ too much recursion, i+1 ok in tail recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion

thanks for your time.

I was learning an Fibonacci function and one of the answer is below:

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    return (function(a, b, i) {
        return (i < n) ? arguments.callee(b, a + b, i + 1) : a;
    })(1, 1, 1);
}
console.log(fibonacci(51))
```

As the arguments.callee is forbidden in strict mode after ES5, so I replace it with a function name. After which, I saw the i + 1 part, and I replace it with an i++, which turns out too much recursion.

```
function x(n){
    return (function y(a, b, i){
        return (i < n) ? y(b, a + b, i++) : a;
    })(1,1,1)
}
console.log(x(51))
```

After a few debug, I found out that the i + 1 works fine, while i++ does not.

So, did I use i++ the wrong place or I havent understood i++ at all?

Thnx again.

Comment: i+1 doesnt change the value of i, it just passes i+1 as a parameter. i++ on the other hand increases the value of i.

Comment: Note that ES5 does not optimize tail recursion. Tools like Babel will optimize it into a loop for you. Here http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=function%20fibonacci(n)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(function%20f(a%2C%20b%2C%20i)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(i%20%3C%20n)%20%3F%20f(b%2C%20a%20%2B%20b%2C%20i%20%2B%201)%20%3A%20a%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)(1%2C%201%2C%201)%3B%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(fibonacci(51))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i+1` means "return value that is one larger than *i*, don't change *i*"

`i++` means "increment *i* by one, but return the original value"

`++i` means "increment *i* by one and return the incremented value"

So in this case if you use `i+1` you're not changing the value of *i*, but you're sending a value one larger than *i* as an argument. You could also use the `++i`, if you would need the value in *i* to change also.

**Examples**

```
i = 10
a = i+1
// a = 11, i = 10

i = 10
a = i++
// a = 10, i = 11

i = 10
a = ++i
// a = 11, i = 11
```

The same applies also for `i-1`, `i--` and `--i`

Answer (score 10):

`i++` increments a number and *returns the old value*.

This means effectively that you're passing `i` everywhere instead of `i + 1`.

It's better to just pass `i + 1` since that's the value you're asking for - but `++i` will also work.

Comment: You could use ++i instead.

Comment: @greenhoorn: You *could*, but it wouldn't make any sense to. `i` isn't subsequently used in the same call, so there's no point in writing back to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is not a question of sense or no sense, he just needs to pass a number which is 1 greater than i. If you increase i or define a new variable greater than i is just a question of how you code. If I'm right, ++i even needs less space than i + 1 (few bits..)

Comment: @greenhoorn: `i+1` vs `++i` -- no difference once minified. :-) But again, you don't throw random dead assignments into your code, right? So why should the OP throw one into this code?

Comment: so basically, when I use i ++ I just mean 'return (function y(b, a+b, 1){return function y (b, a+b, i++)})(1,1,1)' all the time?

Comment: @FadeocKhaos when you use `i++` you're effectively passing `i`

Answer (score 4):

This is because only the output of `i++` is the same as `i + 1`.

But when you use `i++` you also assign the value to `i`.

so

```
var i = 0;
output i++; // 1
output i; // still 1

var i = 0;
output i + 1; // 1
output i; // 0
```